# ASP.NET Core MVC - Delete Button Not Working

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm following along with a tutorial, and we are creating a delete button that accesses a SQL table and then deletes the record based off the ID. I'm not sure what is happening but whenever I am trying to delete it, its returning null.

[Here is how the webpage looks when you first load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lirVt.jpg)

Then you click the delete button and you are taken here:

[Here is the webpage depending on what item you delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjFTd.jpg)

When I try to delete something from the webpage, its not getting the ID properly, since its returning null. I'm not sure if the tutorial did it wrong or if I'm doing something wrong, but even downloading the provided code file, it still doesn't return anything.

Here is my Delete.cshtml:

```html
@model InAndOut.Models.Expense

<h1>Delete Expense</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post" asp-action="DeletePost">
            <input asp-for="ExpenseId" hidden />
           
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NameOfExpense"></label>
                <input asp-for="NameOfExpense" disabled class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Cost"></label>
                <input asp-for="Cost" disabled class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-8 offset-2 row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger w-75" value="Delete" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-sucess" w-75">Back</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller to perform the delete:

```html
    public class ExpenseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public ExpenseController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Expense> objList = _db.Expenses;
            return View(objList);
        }


        // POST Delete
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeletePost(int? id)
        {
            var obj = _db.Expenses.Find(id);
            if(obj == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _db.Expenses.Remove(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        // GET Delete
        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if(id == null || id == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var obj = _db.Expenses.Find(id);
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(obj);
        }
```

Comment: well the hidden variable for the ID is called  "ExpenseId", but your delete expects it to be called "id".

Comment: Oh gosh, I feel stupid now. That fixed it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input asp-for="ExpenseId" hidden />
```

The `asp-for` tag helper generates the `id` and `name` attributes as `ExpenseId`, hence the controller catches `ExpenseId`.

You should change the controller to this:

```
public IActionResult DeletePost(int? ExpenseId)
```

It should work.